# Обход ошибки

Tags: php

Как поймать и ошибку в момент, когда условие ложно и функция не отдает объект? Догадываюсь, что надо использовать исключения, но никогда ими не пользовался, буду благодарен за пример.

```
class hub{
    public function r($condition,$message){
        if ($condition){
            echo $message;
            return $this;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
$o=new hub();
$o->r(true,'continue ')->r(true,'continue')->r(true,'continue')->r(false,'stop')->r(true,'continue');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, конечно сделать так:

```
try{
    if ($condition){
        echo $message;
        return $this;
    }
    else{
        throw new Exception('Error');
    }
}
```

А потом ловить исключение catch'ем. Но я не понимаю сакральный смысл этой операции. По мне, лучше сделать примерно так:

```
if($condition && !$this->errorFlag){
    //...
}
else{
    $this->errorFlag = true;
}
return $this;
```

Дебажится эта конструкция точно тем же способом - через echo или внутренний счетчик вызовов.

Comment: Ну на самом деле мне всего лишь нужно, чтобы цепочка прервалась и далее продолжалось выполнение программы. **UPD**Ну хотя да можно и так и так вы правы.

Answer (score 3):

Может быть используя исключения:

```
class hub{
    public function r($condition,$message){
        if ($condition){
            echo $message;
        }else{
            throw new Exception(
                '$condition is false, with $message="' . $message . '"'
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Соответственно:

```
$o=new hub();
try {
    $o->r(true,'continue')
      ->r(true,'continue')
      ->r(true,'continue')
      ->r(false,'stop')
      ->r(true,'continue');
} catch (Exception $e) {
      echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Соответственно можно сделать свой класс исключений и в нем подробно описать причину чего случилось.